# Can we use OneLogin with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, onelogin, identity-management

We are using azure ad b2c for identity management and SSO for all our applications, So all our products/apps are registered on azure ad b2c directory. Users are also created on azure AD through MS Graph API. So all these users can avail the SSO facility. Now along with azure ad b2c we also want to use OneLogin. Is it possible with the existing azure ad b2c setup? I tried to google it but did not find any concrete answer. Can we add OneLogin as a identity provider like google, facebook in azure ad b2c?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider), you can add any identity provider that supports OAuth 1.0, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, or SAML protocols.